# Creating pdf file with non asii caracters from excel (python)

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, pycharm, reportlab

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code128
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.platypus import Image
import csv
data_file="variteks.csv"
attendee_data=csv.reader(open(data_file,"rb"))
def pdf_creater(data_file):
    attendee_data=csv.reader(open(data_file,"rb"))

    for row in attendee_data:
        barcode_name = row[0]
        barcode_number=row[1]
        barcode_stf=row[2]
        pdf_file_name= barcode_number+ ".pdf"
generate_certificate(barcode_name,barcode_number,barcode_stf,pdf_file_name)

def generate_certificate (barcode_name,barcode_number,barcode_stf,pdf_file_name):
    c= canvas.Canvas(pdf_file_name)#, pagesize=letter)
    c.setPageSize((400,600))
    c.setViewerPreference("FitWindow", "true")

    # first_image
    variteks = "variteks_first.png"
    c.drawImage(variteks, 40,400, width=None, height=None)

    variteks_ce = "variteks_ce.png"
    c.drawImage(variteks_ce, 40, 260, width=None, height=None)

    barcode = code128.Code128(barcode_number,barHeight=30,barWidth = 2)
    barcode.drawOn(c, 10 * mm, 20 * mm)

    #info
    c.drawCentredString(150,100,barcode_name)

    #info
    c.drawCentredString(150,150, barcode_stf)

    #barkod numarasi
    c.drawCentredString(100,40,barcode_number)
    #down info
    c.drawCentredString(150,15,"1 adet ürün içerir. Contains 1 Piece. LOT:",)

    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    print ("writing")
pdf_creater(data_file)
```

I have above code to create sticker for a product. It work fine unless i put Turkish characters into csv file. If i put Turkish character i get following error. Can you please help me with Turkish characters? (ş,ı,ç,ğ,ü,ö)
my code has 2 picture, 3 str, 1 barcode.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/variteks.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/variteks.py", line 57, in <module>
pdf_creater(data_file)
  File "C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/variteks.py", line 23, in pdf_creater
generate_certificate(barcode_name,barcode_number,barcode_stf,pdf_file_name)
  File "C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/variteks.py", line 47, in generate_certificate
c.drawCentredString(150,150, barcode_stf)
  File "C:\Users\muhammedcan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1575, in drawCentredString
width = self.stringWidth(text, self._fontname, self._fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\muhammedcan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1675, in stringWidth
(fontSize,self._fontsize)[fontSize is None])
  File "C:\Users\muhammedcan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfmetrics.py", line 747, in stringWidth
return getFont(fontName).stringWidth(text, fontSize, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\muhammedcan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfmetrics.py", line 360, in stringWidth
return instanceStringWidthT1(self, text, size, encoding=encoding)
  File "src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c", line 748, in instanceStringWidthT1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

edit: This is the full error.
[image: this is what my sticker looks like]

Comment: Could you please show the full error message, up to your own source file. I'd like to know where the error occurs exactly...

Comment: @SergeBallesta edited.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message I can guess that you are using Python2.7 on a Windows system. Windows is unicode friendly, but not really utf-8 friendly. So it is unlikely for your source csv file to be utf-8 encoded. In addition the error message is still a hint:

'utf8' codec can't decode byte **0xfe** in position **0**

Byte 0xfe can never exist in a utf-8 encoded file, neither as a start byte (below 0xf8) nor as a continuation byte (below 0xc0). But it is the windows-1254 code page encoding for `'ş'`. So I assume that your input csv file uses a windows-1254 character set (`'cp1254'` in Python)

On the other end, reportlab only accept utf8 encoded strings or true unicode strings.
What can be done:

- decode all the strings just before feeding reportlab (and pass unicode strings):

  ```
  ...
  coding = 'cp1254'
  ...
      #info
      c.drawCentredString(150,100,barcode_name.decode(coding))

      #info
      c.drawCentredString(150,150, barcode_stf.decode(coding))

      #barkod numarasi
      c.drawCentredString(100,40,barcode_number.decode(coding))
      #down info (this one should already be utf8 encoded thanks to # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      c.drawCentredString(150,15,"1 adet ürün içerir. Contains 1 Piece. LOT:",)
  ```
- use the codecs module to re-encode the file at reading time (and pass utf8 encoded strings)

  ```
  ...
  import csv
  import codecs

  coding = 'cp1254'                   # or change if current encoding is different

  data_file="variteks.csv"
  #attendee_data=csv.reader(open(data_file,"rb"))
  def pdf_creater(data_file):
      attendee_data=csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(open(data_file,"rb"), coding, 'utf8'))
      ...
  ```

Comment: i have an other error. 
    attendee_data=csv.reader(codecs.EncodedFile(open(data_file,"rb"), coding, 'utf8'))
    NameError: global name 'coding' is not defined

Comment: @H.Can : I did not write it in second code sample, but coding should be `'cp1254'` like in first code. Anyway I have edited my answer with it...

Comment: I am sorry to bother you but I have an error again. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/muhammed_hamza_can.py", line 65, in <module>
    pdf_creater()
  File "C:/Users/muhammedcan/PycharmProjects/mp1/muhammed_hamza_can.py", line 55, in pdf_creater
    c.drawCentredString(150,150, barcode_info.decode(coding))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015f' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Files starting with 0xFE could also be big-endian encoded UTF16.  The byte order mark (BOM) is U+FEFF.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: it was my first idea, but the errors occurs while decoding `barcode_stf` which is not the first field.